# Assuming identical base hazards up to a multiplicative constant, what is the probability that event A will happen before event B?

Tags: probability, survival

Let's say I'm a retailer with a finite supply of widgets. Both men and women visit my shop. There are more men who visit my shop than women, but women are more likely to buy a widget.

I'm assuming that (ignoring woman shoppers) the event 'widget bought by a man' can be modelled by a hazard and survival functions $h(t), S(t)$, and that the event 'widget bought by a woman' has the same hazard and survival functions up to a multiplicative constant $h(t)\lambda, S(t)^\lambda$.

I'd like to calculate the probability that a widget gets, by the end of the day ($t=T$), eventually bought by a man, by a woman, or not at all.

First I thought that the probability of 'widget bought by a man' was simply the probability that it gets bought by a man $1 - S(T)$ times the probability that no woman buys it $S(T)^\lambda$, and similarly for the other event. But that doesn't feel right: if a woman would have bought it before the end of the day, but happens to have come to the shop after the man buyer, then you would still have the event 'widget bought by a man'.

It sounds like I need to calculate the probability that the event time of 'bought by man' is less than that of 'bought by woman', but I don't know how to do that.

I think what I'm after is called competing risks but I'm not sure. Any pointers are much appreciated.